# WSO2 API Manager Mashup

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, mashup

Is there any way to create a mash up service using WSO2 API Manager? My goal is to create two Web services, then generate some data on which business logic is applied. This final data then needs to be fed into a third Web service.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use Apache Camel to create a mashup API easily.